# syntax button missing after "li3_quality" package installation

Tags: lithium

I am trying to make four filter work for me on test dashboard
- Affected
- Complexity
- Coverage
- Profiler

As per readme file, I have cloned "li3_quality" in my Lithium app and added the config in app/config/bootstrap/lib  but on frontend I am not able to see "Syntax" button !!

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/li3_quality show "build failed".....I hope this package is working ?

Can someone help?.

Additional - where this phpca needs to get installed?

Please provide a path to tests.

Lithium Syntax Check

Performing 26 rules on 607 classes.
Configuration `li3_quality` has not been defined.
any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: "Syntax" button - it is a caching issue ! but clicking it nothing do not run the syntax check...

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an issue with Multibyte config not being set up. Please see this commit which resolves the issue in the Framework project. You should be able to make this change in your config/bootstrap/g11n.php file:

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/commit/1eaf7549d94cb75e9ce47be649f9a82af4e5e4cd